# Livewire 2.2: Undefined variable slot in app.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using livewire 2.2 with laravel 7.24 in my laravel project. When i load component using

```
Route::get('/path', ComponentClassPath);
```

it works, but when i load my livewire component inside a blade view. For instance, test.blade.php like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @livewire("my-livewire-component")
@endsection
```

it doesn't work and shows the below error:

> Undefined variable: slot (View:
> E:\xampp\htdocs\lw\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) .

app.blade.php

```
<head>
   @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
       {{ $slot }}
   </div>

   @livewireScripts
</body>
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Can you share your ```ComponentClassPath``` too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're using the `@section` directive (where you `@extend` a layout, and use sections), and not the component `$slot` approach (see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#slots), you should be using `@yield` instead of echoing the "special" `$slot` variable.

Alternatively you could go with the slots-approach, but you would generally choose one or the other. Going with that approach means a different structure to your blade files, and there's nothing wrong with either way -- just be consistent about which one you choose.

To continue using sections and extending layouts, simply replace `{{ $slot }}` with `@yield('content')`, like

```
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>
```

Comment: I followed a video tutorial in which they used both at same time. I think that's in version 1.x. Right?

Comment: If i replace $slot with yield('content'), the error goes and the blade files are rendered well. But the issue is the component rendered directly by livewire (not blade) has nothing in it, just empty.

Comment: @MUHAMMADSiyab me too

Comment: In your Livewire component, hope you are rendering this way:
**return view('livewire.componentName')->extends('layouts.app');**

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use `slot` please create component `php artisan make:component Layouts/Login` and on render function in Livewire controller `Http/Livewire/...` add layout

```php
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.pages.login')
            ->layout('components.layouts.login');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

I found that laravel 10 uses x-app-layout

```
<x-app-layout>
Some content here...
</x-app-layout>
```